# How to retrieve all post and its corrensponding comments

Tags: php, database

How to select all post and its corrensponding comments and commentor. Here's my database example:

```
Person:  ID (primary key), Name
Post:    PID (primary key), Pcontent, ID (foreign key to Person)
Comment: CID (primary key), Ccontent, PID (foreign key to Post)
```

And the user's ID is 1. How to get the post, commentor of the post and its comment with an ID 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I haven't tried anything yet. because I don't know what to code -_- . Sorry, that's why Im posting here

Comment: Your database structure isn't very clear. I take it `ID` is a primary key for the `Person` and `Post` tables. Is `Post.PID` a foreign key to the `Person` table? Which is the primary key in the `Comment` table? If you would edit your question, to show which are PKs and which are FKs to which table, that would be helpful.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that you're going to need `JOIN`'s in your query.

Comment: Person-P.K = ID, Post-P.K = PID, Comment-P.K = CID @halfer

Comment: Did you make the database? Not that you don't need to make the names unique between tables. Even the foreign key and the related primary key need not match. Anyway, with the current structure, say you wanted to get all posts made by the given person, you may do something like: `select * from Post where ID = 1;`. That is, from the table named Post, select every record which has an ID of 1.

Comment: There's an edit button just below the post!

Comment: Doesn't the `Comment` table need a foreign key to the user table also? It is connected to the `Post` table, but it is also by a user, I expect.

Comment: Comments could be by multiple users @halfer if I am reading this correctly. Comments are related to posts.

Comment: It is unusual not to want to record who made a comment, but OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generic SQL statement (we do not know which database product you're working with, so any specifics would be lost here) -

```
SELECT `Post`.`Pcontent`, `Person`.`Name`, `Comment`.`Ccontent`
FROM `Post` 
LEFT JOIN `Person`
ON `Post`.`ID` = `Person`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `Comment`
ON `Post`.`PID` = `Comment`.`PID`
WHERE `Person`.`ID` = 1
```

This will get all posts by where user ID is '1' and will get all comments associated with each post.

Comment: And how to echo that sir using while loop? @jay Blanchard

Comment: @Kean: if you haven't yet looked into how to run a query in PHP, we'll generally suggest you find, and work through, some tutorials. There are (literally) thousands of examples on this site - search bar just at the top! This, and your earlier comment of "I haven't tried anything yet", prompts me to encourage you to research questions prior to asking - you'll learn a lot more with that sort of approach.

Comment: What do you mean? You run this query in your database IDE or you make it part of your PHP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I already run your code and it works but my problem now is for example: I only posted 1 post and the ID of that post is 1 , and lets assume that I commented on that post 3 times. When I echo the post, It echoes 3 times like this. `This is my first post : this is my comment1 , This is my first post: This is my comment2, This is my first post: This is my comment 3`

Comment: It is correctly doing its job then.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I make it as a part of my PHP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes. But what I want the result should look like this : `This is my first post: This is my comment1, This is my comment2, THis is my comment3`

Comment: Cool, we're not going to code that for you though. Please go try to code it, then return when you have issues we can help you with.

Comment: @Kean: generally you would make two queries for that. The first one retrieves the post, and the second one all comments related to the post. You don't really want them in the same resultset, since posts and comments are different things, and need to be handled differently.

Comment: That's my issue sir :'(

Comment: Unfortunately A.) your original question never reflected what you were really looking for and, 2. SO is not a coding service. *Please* go make an attempt and if you have issues come back to ask a new question. **Do not** post a question asking for someone to code this for you.

Comment: @halfer Yes sir. I already did that and works fine. First query is for the post and secoond query is for all the comments. Nested while loops.